# Create a rational function with known vertical and slant

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I create a rational function $g(x)$ with these requirements:

- The vertical asymptotes are at 2 and 5
- The function has a slant asymptote $y = 2x+1$
- The y-intercept is 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fulfill the condition on the asymptotes we can set

$$f(x)=\frac{A}{(x-2)(x-5)}+2x+1$$

and by the condition $f(0)=7$ find out A, that is A=60, thus

$$f(x)=\frac{60}{(x-2)(x-5)}+2x+1$$

[Plot of f(x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2060%2F((x-2)(x-5))%2B2x%2B1)

Comment: How did you determine the value 60 to plug in for the numerator

Comment: @CodeMan5000 I've found by the condition $f(0)=A/(10)+1=7\implies A=60$